# Was not declared in this scope error when using private class in C++

Tags: c++, oop, private

I've a class

```
class myClass
{
    private:

       std::list <myInnerClass> mylists;

       class myInnerClass
       {
            // Design for this private class
       }
}
```

I can't understand why the line `std::list <myInnerClass> mylists` gives me the following error:

```
  - Type 'myInnerClass' was not declared in this scope
  - Type 'myInnerClass' could not be resolved
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: `myInnerClass` doesn't exist when you declare `std::list <myInnerClass> mylists;`. Generally you need to declare things before you can use them.

Comment: Since it wasn't, yet, declared, when compilation reached the `std::list <myInnerClass> mylists;` line? Move the declaration of `myInnerClass` above the declaration of such variable.

Comment: Define my list after the definition of my private class solved the problem. Thank you, I thought the position was irrilevant in this case.

Comment: It is "irrelevant" only on member variables and functions. It is quite an annoying edge of C++ IMO.

Comment: Reverse the order of `myinnerclass` so that it precedes `std::list <myInnerClass> mylists;` And don't forget the semicolon.

Answer (score 5):

You use `myInnerClass` before you declare it.

This code will compile:

```
class myClass
{
    private:
       class myInnerClass
       {
            // Design for this private class
       }
       std::list <myInnerClass> mylists;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using your inner class before declaring it

fix:

```
   class myInnerClass
   {
        // Design for this private class
   };

   std::list <myInnerClass> mylists;
```